# Why is np.subtract causing "Killed 9"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Situation: I'm writing a tensor flow program. I'm trying to create a loss function where I compare gram matrices. Calculating the gram matrices seems to go well - or at least the program doesn't crash. However, after I calculate the gram matrices I want to do element wise subtraction, element wise squaring, and then sum up all the elements. The program seems to crash when I attempt to do the element wise subtraction. Here is (what I think is) the relevant code:

```
def _gram_matrix(self, F, N, M):
    print("in gram")
    F = np.reshape(F,(M,N))
    F_trans = np.transpose(F)


    return np.dot(F,F_trans)

def _single_style_loss(self, a, g):
    print("in single style loss")
    print("a shape ",a.shape)
    N = a.shape[3]
    M = a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]
    gram_a = self._gram_matrix(a,N,M)
    gram_g = self._gram_matrix(g,N,M)
    print("out of gram")
    multiplier = 1/(4*N*N*M*M)
    print("leaving single style loss")
    return_val = np.subtract(gram_a,gram_g)
    print("subtract was fine")
    return_val = np.square(return_val)
    print("square was fine")
    array_sum = np.sum(return_val)
    print("sum was fine")
    array_sum = multiplier*array_sum
    print("multiplier was fine")
    print("going to return ",array_sum)
    return array_sum

def _style_loss(self, A):
    print("in style loss")
    loss = 0;
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(self.input_img.assign(self.initial_img))
        generated_layers = sess.run([getattr(self.vgg,layer) for layer in self.style_layers])
        sess.run(self.input_img.assign(self.style_img))#reset input_img to style img
        for i in range(len(self.style_layer_w)):
            print("len ",self.style_layer_w)
            print("len generated layers",len(generated_layers))
            print("len style layers",len(A))
            loss += self.style_layer_w[i]*self._single_style_loss(A[i],generated_layers[i])
            print("loss ",loss)
        self.style_loss = loss
    print("out of style loss")
```

so the error I get is: "leaving single style loss
Killed: 9" This is why I conclude the next line (the np.subtract line) is the problem. Sadly, I do not know why this line is a problem and I would greatly appreciate whatever insight anyone could offer. Thanks!

Comment: Might be a memory limit causing the OS to kill the python process. Can you try with smaller matrices?

Comment: Why don't you use TensorFlow data structures and operations?

Comment: Thanks guys! Turned out it was an OS memory limit, and reducing the size fixed the problem.